# Spring 4.1.7 and spring security 4.0.1 Spring Beans issue

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to develop a Web project which uses latest version of spring framework-4.1.7 and spring security version 4.0.1.

The problems I face is namespace spring beans problem in spring security xml file

**Spring Beans Problem**

1. Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.
2. You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.   spring-security.xml

**My pom.xml**

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End spring Security -->
```

**Spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <openid-login />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Where is the conflict happening? what set of bean configs should I use for spring security. Is the above pom file dependency and spring security version conflicts? Can anyone suggest

Comment: Post more relevant information of your pom, what is the `spring-security.version` property value.

Comment: 4.0.1.RELEASE - as i mentioned in the topic

Comment: Why do you have a specific version and a property notion in there? Also where do you get the errors during deployment or in your IDE (if it is the latter ignore them Eclipse is borked imho regarding XML validation).

Comment: I get error in spring security.xml IDE near the <http> line of the code. And also in detail I can see errors in Markers View in sts

Comment: Ignore them... As mentioned eclipse (or any IDE based on Eclipse) is borked when it comes to XML validation (IMHO that is).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498577/configuration-issue-in-spring-security

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916993/spring-security3-you-cannot-use-a-spring-security-2-0-xsd-schema

Comment: @underdag those aren't relevant as those are different from this (he is using Spring Security 4 and that probably doesn't have support for in the used STS version). His declaration is fine nothing wrong with that. Next to that when it comes to validation Eclipse is borked (imho that is).

Comment: I use  3.5.1.RELEASE sts Version. And Is it fine to have url versionless in springsecurity. xml? like this <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">